# R ggplot2 two-level facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet, facet-wrap

I would like to edit the facet labels of a ggplot graphics with facet_wrap as follows:

1. I would like to write the ALPHA and BETA labels only in the top row.
2. I would like to write FIRST, SECOND and THIRD only on the left side and only once per row.

Would such a thing be possible?

Alternatively, I tried to work with grid arrange, but the "pure" ggplot graph looks better, and the code is easier to manipulate (less copy and paste for each row). Also I ran into issues with row height with grid_arrange (some plots god cut off).

Example:

```
Anames <- list(
  '1'="FIRST",
  '2'="SECOND",
  '3'="THIRD")

Bnames <- list(
  'A'="ALPHA",
  'B'="BETA")

plot_labeller <- function(variable,value){

# http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=175

  if (variable=='variable') {
    return(Anames[value])
  } else {
    return(Bnames[value])
  }
}

tdat <- data.frame("variable" = c(rep(seq(1,3),10)), # Group Factor 1 
                   "B" = c(rep(seq(1,2),15)), # Group Factor 2
                   "time" = c(1:30),
                   "value" = sample(1:100,30))
tdat$B <- ifelse(tdat$B==1,"A","B")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=tdat, aes(x=time,y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~variable+B,
             labeller=plot_labeller,
             ncol=2,scales="free_y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparing two types of variables, it's often easier to use `facet_grid`:

```
ggplot(data=tdat, aes(x=time,y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    facet_grid(rows = vars(variable), cols = vars(B), 
               labeller = plot_labeller, scales="free_y", switch = 'y')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `facet_grid` to do this. `switch` is set to "y" to plot the labels on the left side.

```
ggplot(data=tdat, aes(x=time,y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    facet_grid(variable ~ B,
               labeller=plot_labeller,
               scales="free_y",
               switch = "y")
```